# app.locals returning variable names instead of strings

Tags: javascript, express, environment-variables, handlebars.js

I've been trying to utilize Express and Handlebars to pass in process.env variables.

server.js

```
app.locals.apiKey = process.env.apiKey;
```

index.handlebars

```
console.log({{apiKey}});
```

I've been playing around with this for a while and even when looking through the internet it seems as if {{apiKey}} returns a variable instead of a string.

It wouldn't matter where I put quotes around it because the console keeps returning

```
SCRIPT5009: 'myapikey1234' is not defined.
```

Is there a workaround for this? I feel like every post related to app.locals, no one has an issue with this.

Comment: How about `console.log('{{apiKey}}');`?

Comment: thank you! didn't even realize how simple that would be, never tried it because I thought it would just return '{{apiKey}}'...